# Android Setting|( file ) Configuration

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

i have the following method to save connection string in app setting , is there is any android file like (web config in asp.net) which handle the information from which user can "read write"?

```
public static System.String StrConnectionstring
            {
                get 
                {
                    if (DB._StrConnectionstring == null)
                    {
                        return AppSettings.GetConnectionSettings("DSN");
                    }
                    return DB._StrConnectionstring;
                }
                set { DB._StrConnectionstring = value; }
            }
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Shared Preferences :

**Declaration :**

```
public static final String MYPREFS = "MySharedPreferenceFile";
SharedPreferences settings;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
```

**Initialization :**

```
settings = context.getSharedPreferences(MYPREFS, 0);
editor = settings.edit();
```

**To store values :**

```
editor.putString("Name","test");
editor.commit();
```

**To retrieve values :**

```
settings.getString("Name",""); // here value field is for to specify default value
```

Thanks.

Comment: @mak you can refer this link for theory explanations and example. [ http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref ] . Thanks.